# Is there a Xcode build setting reference for document directory?

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell

I'm looking to see if any XCode `build setting reference` such as `${PROJECT_NAME}` exists for the document directory. I have some files saved to the document directory and I would like to run a script that would target that file. The document directory is from:

```objectivec
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentDirectory = documentDirectories[0];
```

I searched through [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) but maybe I missed it.

For example, if there is a "MyNotes.txt" in the iOS App document directory, I would like to run a script targeting that file (copy and pasting it to another folder).

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “Xcode variable”? Do you mean a project configuration variable? A project doesn't have a document directory. An app has a document directory. Do you want the app to find its document directory at runtime?

Comment: And what is `pathInDocumentDirectory`?

Comment: @rmaddy I think he's following the Big Nerd Ranch's _iOS Programming Guide_: https://books.google.com/books?id=gj7tjxGztGwC&lpg=PT320&ots=pAW7-6_nl3&dq=pathInDocumentDirectory&pg=PT321#v=onepage&q=pathInDocumentDirectory&f=false

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited it for clarify.

Comment: There's not going to be a build-time reference for that path, because it's determined at run time. It's going to be different depending upon what device/configuration you run this on.

Comment: I can accept that there might not be a build-time reference for that. Another question then. I was playing around with some of the variables and TARGET_TEMP_DIR results in something like /Users/okyretina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IouApp2-hegsenjlsuxcnydgcniffqjpconh/Build/Intermediates/IouApp2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Iouapp.build. It's close but no cigar.

Comment: The Documents directory is part of the app sandbox, and doesn't exist in the build output. You would need to run your script on the device, and you cannot run scripts on an iOS device unless it is jailbroken. Or did you just want to run the script on your Mac to access the app sandbox in the simulator?

Comment: Just the mac and not on the device. I want to access the app sandbox in the simulator. It's more for personal scripting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no Xcode build setting for the document directory. You can add a empty Run Script to your build phases and check “Show environment variables in build log” to verify.

You can figure out the document directory by using the `simctl` command and then checking a bunch of plists. It's a bit roundabout. For example, this script finds the directory for an app with bundle identifier `com.dqd.test`, in the currently-booted simulated device:

```
#!/bin/bash

bundle=com.dqd.test

appdir=$(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted "$bundle")
appdataparentdir="${appdir%%/data/Containers/Bundle/*}"/data/Containers/Data/Application
for dir in "$appdataparentdir"/*; do
    if plutil -extract MCMMetadataIdentifier xml1 -o - "$dir/.com.apple.mobile_container_manager.metadata.plist" | grep ">$bundle<" >/dev/null; then
        break
    fi
    dir=
done

if [ "$dir" != "" ]; then
    echo "$dir/Documents"
fi
```

Result:

```
:; ./getdocdir
/Users/mayoff/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3699C4CE-D6F3-4E6E-B1AC-0B35D78BFD80/data/Containers/Data/Application/32068FBC-6191-4F5E-B18F-D47D8778D3BE/Documents
```

Note that each simulated device has its own UUID, its own subdirectory in the under `CoreSimulator/Devices`, and its set of containers, so the output will change if you boot a different simulated device.